# Dask dataframe saving to_csv for incremental data - Effecient Writing to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have an existing code for reading streaming data and storing it using `pandas` DataFrame (new data comes in every 5 mins), I then capture this Data Category wise (~350 categories).

Next, I write all the **new** data (as this is to be incrementally stored) using `to_csv` in a loop.

**The Pseudocode is given below:**

```py
    for row in parentdf.itertuples(): #insert into <tbl> .
        mycat = row.category # this is the ONLY parameter which is passed to the Key function below.
        try:
            df = FnforExtractingNParsingData(mycat ,NumericParam1,NumericParam1) 
    
            df.insert(0,'NewCol',sym)
            df = df.assign(calculatedCol = functions1(params))
            df = df.assign(calculatedCol1 = functions2(params),20))
            df = df.assign(calculatedCol3 = functions3(More params),20))
            df[20:].to_csv(outfile, mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

The category-wise reading and storing in csv takes **2 Mins-Per cycle***. This is close to **.34 Seconds for each writing of the 350 Categories incrementally**.
I am wondering whether I can make the above process faster & efficient by using `dask` dataframes.

I looked up dask.org and didn't get any clear answers, looked at the use cases as well.

**Additional details:** I am using Python 3.7 and **Pandas 0.25**,
Further the above code above doesn't return any errors, even though we have completed good amount of Exception handling already on the above.
My key function i.e. **FnforExtractingNParsingData** is fairly resilient and is working as desired for a long time.

Comment: .. This will be my first time trying to use Dask, I am open to suggestions for any ways which I can use to minimize the procedure runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're reading data into a Pandas DataFrame every 5 minutes and then writing it to disk.  The question doesn't mention some key facts:

- how much data is ingested every 5 minutes (10MB or 10TB)?
- where is the code being executed (AWS Lambda or a big cluster of machines)?
- what data operations does `FnforExtractingNParsingData` perform?

Dask DataFrames can be written to disk as multiple CSV files in parallel, which can be a lot faster than writing a single file with Pandas, but it depends.  Dask is overkill for a tiny dataset.  Dask can leverage all the CPUs of a single machine, so it can scale up on a single machine better than most people realize.  For large datasets, Dask will help a lot.  Feel free to provide more details in your question and I can give more specific suggestions.

Comment: 10 MB..  Local Machine Execution.  FnforExtractingNParsingData Converts the streaming Data into a df for us to Write into Csv. Now that I have answered the 3 Key Questions. This particular approach isn't reqd for the moment !! I have another approach which is wokring for me.